# Package installed through Homebrew was not found in pkg-config search path

Tags: ios, swift-package-manager, pkg-config

When trying to link to a system-installed library through *Swift Package Manager*, specifying it under `pkgConfig`, it says that the installed *package wasn't found in the pkg-config search path*. It suggests finding the .pc file that comes with the module but there isn't one.

How do I go about linking the library with SPM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I went about it is creating the .pc file and putting it into `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`, where .pc files are kept, on your own.

.pc files essentially follow the following format:

- Defined variables
- Name, Description, Version
- Libs and Cflags

So for example:

```
prefix=/usr/local/ModuleFolder
libdir=${prefix}/lib
includedir=${prefix}/include

Name: samplemodule
Description: Appears in a Stack Overflow answer.
Version: 1.0.0
Libs: -L${libdir}
Cflags: -I${includedir}
```

You can check if pkg-config now detects the file with `pkg-config yourmodule --libs --cflags` and if so then it should work in *Package.swift* as well.

If the application was installed through Homebrew, the missing .pc file issue should probably be reported to the developers, although they may not want to implement it in some cases.

More info on pkg-config files can be found at [https://people.freedesktop.org/~dbn/pkg-config-guide.html](https://people.freedesktop.org/%7Edbn/pkg-config-guide.html)